# Calculating Interest (Java), the program should print the projected account balance after an arbitrary numbers of years

Tags: java

Please help me. Basically the program should Ask the user to input a number representing the initial balance of a savings account. Assign this number to a double variable called balance.
Ask for a number representing the yearly rate of interest (in percent) on the account. Divide this number by 100.0 and assign it to a double variable called rate. I have to use a loop to update the balance as it changes year by year. I am stuck on that part. Here is the code I have so far :

```
   public static void calcInterest(){
System.out.println("Please enter the account balance : ");
     System.out.println("Please enter the annual interest rate : ");
     System.out.println("Please enter the number of years : ");
     Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
     double balance = input.nextDouble();
     double y = input.nextDouble();
     double rate = (y/100);
     int years = input.nextInt();


     }
```

Comment: Why do you need to loop it for the years? Why not calculate it right away using Math.pow? Do you need to show the balance for every single year up to and including the value of years ?

Comment: umm that's what I was told to do and nope, not every single year has to be shown, just the balance for the entered year. How would you do it with Math.pow?

Comment: This sort of sounds like a beginning Java class, so I assume they want you to use `while` instead of `for` loop. Create a `counter=1` variable and a `while` loop that increments the counter each iteration and stops when `counter==years`. Then of course add `rate * balance` to `balance` each time

Comment: yeah I just started doing Java and how would that look on the code? Structure wise? Thank you for that :).

Answer (score 1):

There's no good reason to use a loop in this case, but I guess it's for learning purposes.
You can make a loop that calculates the new balance a year at a time like this:

```
for(int i = years; i > 0; i--)
    balance = balance * y;
```

Alternatively use Math.pow(this follows the formula startvalue * rate of change^time = result):

```
balance = balance * Math.pow(y, years);
```

Comment: that makes a lot more sense now :). It worked :D. Thank you !

Comment: No problem, hope you understand how it works, otherwise oracle has some good documentation on for loops https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: will deffo check it out, just want to check if it is working how I think it is working. Thank you :).